# workaround for dynamic formatting specs with fmt

Tags: c++, constexpr, fmt, gcc11, gcc10

Is there a way to use fmt with a spec that is computed at runtime.

Noticed that with gcc 10 this code worked fine but not with modern gcc.

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

const char* get_spec(bool test)
{ // image this is implemented in some other .cpp file
    return test ? "->{}" : "{}<-";
}

int main() {
    const char* non_constexpr = get_spec(true);
    fmt::print(non_constexpr,1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oh9n3cEnT

Comment: Supply `->` and `<-` as strings. `fmt::print("{}{}{}", (test ? "->" : ""), 1, (test ? "" : "<-"));`

Comment: @user7860670 Sure but would like to get the format strings at runtime, or from some library in another translation unit.

Comment: Amount and types of the arguments passed are fixed at comiple-time therefore format string compatibility should be checked at compile-time as well.

Comment: There's a bunch of similar duplicated questions on SO.

Comment: Same issue with `std::format`, by the way...

Comment: I created a wrapper that calls std::format or fmt::format and I'm not sure why I get constexpr errors. Seems silly to ask yet another question, but I can't figure out how to get this signature to work and delegate to either std::format or fmt::format. I tried assigning the format string as a constexpr before the call to pear::format and that didn't work either.

https://github.com/eighty4/pear.ng/blob/osx-fmtlib/desktop/bin/pear_cli/pear_cli.cc#L38

https://github.com/eighty4/pear.ng/blob/osx-fmtlib/desktop/bin/pear_cli/format.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `fmt::runtime()`:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

const char* get_spec(bool test)
{ // image this is implemented in some other .cpp file
    return test ? "->{}" : "{}<-";
}

int main() {
    const char* non_constexpr = get_spec(true);
    fmt::print(fmt::runtime(non_constexpr),1);
}
```

Like always, gcc has bad error descriptions. The problem is that the normal constructor for format patterns is `consteval` in C++20, so you cannot pass a runtime format to it.

For that purpose, just use `fmt::runtime()` around your runtime format pattern.

In case of C++20's `std::format` problem, you need to use `std::vformat` to resolve the problem as mentioned in cpp ref.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fmt::vprint`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv4N3fmt6vprintE11string_view11format_args) ([`std::vprint_unicode`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/vprint_unicode) in C++23) for runtime format string

```
const char* non_constexpr = get_spec(true);
int arg = 1;
fmt::vprint(non_constexpr, fmt::make_format_args(arg));
```